# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, ssl, httpwebrequest

I have provide everything depends any question on stackoverflow, but why it's not working.

> Note: this code works fine on server side, but locally it's not
>   working and also site isn't filter, so no need for proxy.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://daroo.shop");
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident / 7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko";

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                    | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;



HttpWebResponse response = null;
try
{
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timers = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseTime = timers.Elapsed.Milliseconds;
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
//The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
}
```